# How to MySQL Between Multiple Where Clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, between

I want to display the products with price between 10k and 30k with category_id = 1, or category_id = 2.

this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE price BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
AND
category_id = '2' OR category_id = '3'
ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC
```

but I get all product in these category and no get product with price between 10k and 30k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to think about your order of operations on this, you want this

```
WHERE (price BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000)
AND
(category_id = '2' OR category_id = '3')
```

Answer (score 2):

Enforce the logic with suitable bracketing

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE price BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
AND
(category_id = '2' OR category_id = '3')
ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `OR` predicate needs to be in between parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE price BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
AND (category_id = '1' OR category_id = '2')
ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC
```

Alternatively, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE price BETWEEN 10000 AND 30000
AND category_id IN ('1', '2')
ORDER BY name ASC, price ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this is happening, you need to know about [operator precedence](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-or/). You might remember from school (I barely do) that multiplication and division are evaluated before addition - same concept here.

The best thing to do (for both code readability and making your intentions clear) is to use parentheses to force the operators to be evaluated in the order you want them to.

Comment: Good you mention this. This is the key of the issue.